# Dynamic Column Values in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-custom-visuals

I have the below sample table and I want to make a filter where If I select Daily, to show the aggregated sales on a daily level with the days in the column headers, if I select monthly to show the months in columns and the aggregated sales for the month below and the same with week.

Is there any way using Dax or any other tool in PBI to allow me to have dynamic column values based on the filter?

Examples of same table and visuals below

Thank you

Sample Table

[image]

Monthly Filter
[image]

Weekly Filter

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage time-intelligence hierarchy here. If your date field is datetime type, Power BI will auto-hierarchy this. Then you can drag the hierarchy date field into the visualization. By default it will include Year, Quarter, Month, Day.

You can remove the sections you don't need and then create bookmarks to snapshot certain filters.

This is one method to do this, let me know if it was helpful to get you going.